# how to get war to deploy on tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat, war

On Ubuntu 16.04, I stop the tomcat7 server with:

```
sudo tomcat7 stop
```

Then I created a war file as follows:

```
mkdir test
created index.html within test
jar -cf test.war test
```

I copy the war file into the webapps directory:

```
webapps/test.war
```

I bring up tomcat using the command:
    sudo service tomcat7 start

which works, so that the following url shows the server working:

```
localhost:8080
```

As I understand it, the following URL should go to the .war file
    localhost:8080/test

It does not work. (404 error) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need web.xml also for the new app test. Refer this link. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/deploying-a-web-app-into-an-app-server-container.html else you can access the static HTML page directly by giving the whole URL. http://localhost:8080/test/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below procedure to create war file:

1) mkdir test
2) Go to the test directory and create index.html
3) create war file using the below command:

```
jar -cf test.war .
```

4) Move created test.war file into the webapps folder. Restart tomcat service and test.After restart check your webapps folder for an extracted folder test. You will see index.html file inside `webapps/test` folder.

`jar -cf test.war test` command will create test folder inside test.war. so you need to access i.e http://localhost/test/test/